# webSocket.send() is not executed in react js?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, websocket

I am working with WebSocket in reactjs, but WebSocket.send is not executing on the onClick event.
here I create WebSocket

```
 const ws = new WebSocket("ws://192.168.18.112:8000/ws/notification/");
```

connect to WebSocket

```
 ws.onopen = (e) => {
    console.log("connect");
  };
```

here is my onClick function

```
  const sendNotification = (e) => {
    console.log("click");
    if (ws.readyState === WebSocket.OPEN && message !== "") {
      ws.send("message");
      console.log("Sending message"); // this console is execute
    } else if (ws.readyState === WebSocket.CONNECTING) {
      ws.addEventListener("open", () => sendNotification());
      console.log("Connecting state");
      console.log("Not Send");
    } else {
      console.log("nothing happen");
    }
  };
```

so here is my problem I am unable to find bug or problem in my code.

Comment: Can you post the console output?

Comment: yes first the ws is connected, and than in function all conditions are call randomly but the line of code ``` ws.send("message")``` is skiped or not executing.

Comment: Change `console.log(‘click’)` to also log `we.readyState` and `message`. That might give you some clues about the cause.

Comment: 'sending message' console was also printed out

Answer (score 0):

try this **W3CWebSocket**. Also i don't think there si a "/" after notification after **ws/notification** double check if your end point correct or not.

```
mport React, { Component } from 'react';
import { w3cwebsocket as W3CWebSocket } from "websocket";

const client = new W3CWebSocket('ws://192.168.18.112:8000/ws/notification/');

class App extends Component {
  componentWillMount() {
    client.onopen = () => {
      console.log('WebSocket Client Connected');
    };
    client.onmessage = (message) => {
      console.log(message);
    };
  }
  
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        Practical Intro To WebSockets.
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

Comment: I have tried this approach too. but unfortunately its also not working